# Make svg:path easily clickable

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working with [d3](http://d3js.org) for visualizing a graph. I used svg:path for drawing the links. I want my links to be clickable. I put onclick event on them but it only works if you click on the line itself and it is too narrow to click on. So I decided to add another path as a child to the original one and make it invisible and fatter so the user can click on it easily. This is my code for adding the dummy paths as child of original one.

```
paths=link.append("svg:path")
.attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
.style("stroke",function(d){
    if(d.Uid=="merged")return merged_edge_color;
    else return "#000";
}).style("stroke-width",function(d){
    if(d.Uid=="merged")return 4;
    else return 2;
}).on("mouseover", edge_click);

paths.append("svg:path").attr("class","path_clickable")
      .style("stroke-width",5).style("stroke","#000")
      .on("mouseover", edge_click);
```

The edge_click function is my function to handle the clicks.
And I update the *d* attribute of dummy paths with respect to the original paths. Now the problem is that when I load the graph I cannot see the dummy paths that I've added. This is what I see in the Firefox inspector:

```
<path d="M519.6082605229858,264.2807401557369A963797.516994379,963797.516994379 0 0,1 465.2163670278527,322.64265504894405" style="stroke-width: 5; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="path_clickable"></path>
      <path d="M519.6082605229858,264.2807401557369A963797.516994379,963797.516994379 0 0,1 465.2163670278527,322.64265504894405" style="stroke-width: 5; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="path_clickable"></path>
```

There is no difference between them except the class name. but the inspector doesn't show anything when I select the dummy one.

Comment: You can't append `path`s to `path`s. You could append both to a `g` element to group them.